# Enable navigation buttons and address area in XFCE

Tags: xfce

I just installed the xfce Desktop environment  and I can't find the navigation buttons and the address area in the file manager.

[image]

in other Desktop environment  I can find this feature :

[image]

How can I enable this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on XFCE version. On 13.04, you can switch the layout in `View > Location selector`.

[image]

Comment: thanks it works, can I know which theme are using ?

Comment: I am using the default 13.04 one - Greybird - see http://screencloud.net/v/2mhA

Comment: And you can get Greybird by `sudo apt-get install shimmer-themes` if you don't have a default Xubuntu.